# If-Then statement Looping

Tags: vba, messagebox

I have created an If-Then statement code that will open up a Message Box if there would be a duplicate.

My Problem is that when there is a duplicate, i cannot exit the Message Box. It's like it is in a loop.

My code here is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Sheets("IELTS Passed").Range("O1").Value = "True" Then
    MsgBox "This Applicant already exist!"
End If
```

By the way, the Range("O1") contains the formula which will look for any duplicates within the sheet "IELTS Passed".

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Can you not exit the message box, or is it in a loop?

Comment: Are there other events happening on the page?

Comment: @ashleedawg I could exit the message box but it would take a lot of clicking on the close button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a certainly good option is running the If-Then part **only** when a change is happening in the cells which have a modifying effect on this O1 cell.

Use the target argument for that:

```
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, RangeWhichAffectsThisCell) is Nothing Then

‘Your code comes here

End if
```

Another way:

At the end of your code, remove the applicant entry (wherever its cell is) which caused the MessageBox to pop up. I assume this sets the O1 cell to “False”.

But, we do not know all the details so we canot give you a 100% accurate answer.

Comment: Hi @iSpain17, the code you have provided works perfectly! Thank you very much!